# How to generate an answer key of a multiple-choice exam?

Tags: tables, exam, answers

I have a number of multiple-choice questions. I want to produce an answer key (a small table with nx5 cells where the answer places are somehow highlighted).

My code (from another post ) is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\AnswersList{}
\newcommand\AddAnswer[1]{\edef\AnswersList{\AnswersList#1\endgraf}}

\newcommand*{\mc}[6]{%
    % code to display the multiple choice for #1...#5
    \AddAnswer{#6,}%
}%

\begin{document}

\mc{2}{3}{5}{7}{11}{3}
\mc{2}{3}{5}{7}{11}{5}


The list of answers are:

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\foreach \answer in \AnswersList {%
    \item \answer
}%
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The answer key may be something similar to the following image (in Persian or English).

[image]

Comment: What has your MWE to do with what you are trying to achieve?